# Nativescript Positioning TabView at the top for IOS

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript

Are there any way to positioning TabView at the top for IOS instead of bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS you can not set your TabView at the top.
Alternative solution using SegmentedBar can be found at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37134680/tabview-stick-at-the-top-on-ios-nativescipt)

Comment: TabView for andriod has the feature of swiping between tabs which SegmentedBar has not, Do you suggest any solutions?

Comment: You can implement your own gestures events for the content that you will load for each segmentedBarItem https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/gestures#swipe

Comment: For example... wrap your content for each segmentedBar item in a container element (let's say GridLayout) and attach swipe gesture to it with a navigation logic...